# ATT assembly language arithmetic

Tags: assembly, att

```
Address    Value         Register    Value
0x100      0xFF          %eax        0x100 
0x104      0xAB          %ecx        0x1
0x108      0x13          %edx        0x3
0x10C      0x11

Instruction                        Destination                Value
imull  $16, (%eax, %edx, 4)        ___________                _____
```

I keep getting 0x10C as the destination (which is correct). But for some reason when I multiply 10C * 16 (source * destination) I get 1708 which is incorrect. Can someone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: AT&T syntax needs to die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't multiply 0x10C by 16, you multiply what's at address 0x10C, which is 0x11, by 16. And that gives you 0x110 (or 272).